# Rails 4 with cofffeescript, unwanted jquery sortable detatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I use ruby on rails 4 with jquery-ui-rails gem. And some list have sortable jquery function.

```
$ ->  
  $('#projects').sortable
        handle: '.handle'
        opacity: 0.4
        update: ->
            $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

This is my code, not apply tab indent.

Problem:

List actually working on first connect project page, and I connect a list into show page, 
then I click Back links. Not working sortable

What happen?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have turbolinks enabled. Read about them here: [github/rails/turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/).

Problem is that when you change page with clicking, turbolinks only loads new page by ajax and updates current page. Without reloading any css and js. So `$ ->` will not work after first load.

There are two solutions to this problem:

First, use `document.addEventListener "page:load", ->` instead of `$ ->`.

Or second, remove turbolinks gem from `Gemfile` and remove its `require` from `application.js`.